# Fix Better Touch Tool so that it doesn't prevent sleep?

Tags: sleep-wake, bettertouchtool

I noticed that the application [Better Touch Tool](http://www.boastr.de/) is preventing my Mac from going to sleep. The screen will shut off, but the computer won't go to sleep. Is there a way to disable any of the settings to not cause this behavior, or do we need to wait for a fix from the developer?

I'm hoping to avoid a solution such as running [Please Sleep](http://www.dragonone.com/products/macosx/pleasesleep/).

(I reported this bug to the developer.)

Comment: You're certain this is only happening when BTT is running? I use BTT and haven't noticed this behavior.

Comment: @kccricket: yes, I've tried it many times and BTT is always the problem. It will still turn the monitor off, but the computer won't go to sleep. That's one of the reasons this bug is hard to catch. Are you sure that your computer is actually going to sleep and it's not just the monitor that is going to sleep? See [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30417/how-can-i-tell-the-difference-between-display-sleep-vs-computer-sleep-on-my-mac) for detecting the difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

After a year, you might need to publish the bug report and see if others are seeing similar problems. Has the developer responded to your bug report?

I can't reproduce this behavior, so perhaps it's related to your OS or something else on your setup that's interacting poorly with this software.